# I do not see SESSION vars when calling subdomain script with Jquery (ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cookies, subdomain

I've got a problem. I hope you'll help me to solve it.

I'm creating chat with LONG POLLING. To keep main domain ajax requests (send message) untouched (unqueued), I had to put my long-polling script to subdomain.
So I've got 2 "domains"

foo.cz
channel.foo.cz

I do not mind about any Same Origin Policy right now as I put

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

at top of that script. I also do use

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.foo.cz');
```

in all scripts (sending, receiving, chatting room).

For debugging, i've got this in my channel.foo.cz/getNews.php:

```
print_r($_SESSION);
print_r($_COOKIE);
die();
```

My problem is:

1. I do load chatting room
2. Ajax (jquery) requests channel.foo.cz/getNews.php
3. getNews.php returns this:

   array()array()
4. It look that cookies and session isn't setted up. But! If I look into my FF cookie browser, I do see that domain for these cookies set in chatRoom is .foo.cz
5. If I try to copy ajax request uri and paste it into browser url, it returns me

   array([username] => martin)array([SESSID] => some1D65a4s6d54asd)

How is that possible? Sorry for long question and thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it. 
Browser is restricting to send cookies to another subdomain 
So I have used iframe which is sending request to my subdomain. However, there were some problem when there were vanishing sessions. Solution? php.ini:

```
suhosin.session.cryptdocroot=Off

suhosin.cookie.cryptdocroot=Off
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at [session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) function's third parameter. It sets the domain name where the cookie with SID is valid in.

Comment: I said that there is ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.bidmanie.cz');
When I look into FF cookie browser I see correct domain. I now noted that jquery DOES NOT SEND SESSION ID, so I'm receiving new session ID everytime!

Comment: So it looks like rather some Javascript or jQuery bug.

Comment: I tried this: .ajax({timeout: 52000,headers: {Cookie: "PHPSESSID="+SSID},url:'http://channel.foo.cz/getNews.php?__='+SSID}); but request header doesn't change (no cookie: header specified)

Comment: BTW Ondeji, could you give me some contact, like Skype? I would like if you could help me directly, we're speaking in same language (CZ) ;)

Comment: No, sorry. I don't like giving my private contact info, because you have much bigger probability of getting the answer if you ask on a public site like SO. Also, I like to answer questions voluntarily and not if I'm forced to by asking directly on IM. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: Thats ok. But I tried much networks and forums, nobody helped me. I think you're my last chance :/